# Short story about climbing a mountain with an alien

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story I read years ago about mountain climbing with an alien. The alien’s name started with a K.  The title was alliterative - “Climbing K2 with K???”

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is *[On K2 with Kanakaredes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3975.Worlds_Enough_Time)*, a 2001 novelette by Dan Simmons.

> A terrifying ascent up the frigid, snow-swept slopes of K2 shatters preconceptions and reveals the true natures of four climbers, one of whom is not human.

If memory serves, a human climber agrees (reluctantly) to sherpa for an alien up K2 in return for the promise of climbing up a mountain on their homeworld. The alien dies during the ascent but their mate(?) agrees to uphold the promise and we end with the human climber preparing to climb the highest mountain on their planet.

Comment: I'm sure someone can correct my faulty memories but I haven't got time to re-read it and check!

Comment: Thank you. That is it!

Comment: I've rejected the edit because the quote is from the link.